# How to abort script loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxhr

Is it possible to stop loading of the JS file loaded in the below way, are there any event handlers?

```
function makeScript(url){    
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    //when this line is executed the script will be loaded by the browser
    //is there an event where the below script loading can be stopped based                                                                   
    //on some condition                        
    document.head.appendChild(script); 
}
```

I do not want to load the script via ajax call as the js file does not appear under sources tab of Chrome Debugger Tool. There are possible solutions like using `//# sourceURL=dynamicScript.js`, but I will have to put this line in all the js files. I do not want to edit all the js files.If change is localized to 1 place it is good.

Comment: Depending on the condition, yes, you can; however, if the condition has to do with the size or contents of the script, then you will have to use XMLHttpRequest to load your script. If this is the case, then I can provide a good answer for you.

Comment: Suppose there are 2 links, clicking on each link loads the js file using the `makeScript()`.If the user clicks on the first link and quickly clicks on second link, I want to abort the loading of first link's js file. If the loading of js file is not stopped then there may be TypeErrors in the script because when the another link is clicked the first link's variable are deleted which will be used by the loading script. As it cannot find those variables, there will be TypeError.

Answer (score 1):

After your comments

> Suppose there are 2 links, clicking on each link loads the js file using the makeScript().If the user clicks on the first link and quickly clicks on second link, I want to abort the loading of first link's js file. If the loading of js file is not stopped then there may be TypeErrors in the script because when the another link is clicked the first link's variable are deleted which will be used by the loading script.

Here is my piece of idea

You can maintain a global variable which will hold the script to be loaded. Depending on this variable you can execute the `document.head.appendChild(script);` line of code.

Example code

```
var scriptFilesConfig; //make this global scope variable
```

and on click of each link assign this url into the global variable.

So lets say you clicked on the first link then the variable would be

```
scriptFilesConfig = "firstscript.js";
```

Ok now I immediately clicked on the second link, then you must assign this url to the variable. So now your object will be like.

```
scriptFilesConfig = "secondScript.js";
```

Now at any given point you will execute the `document.head.appendChild(script);` only if the url of the script matches with the global vairable.

So your code would be like

```
function makeScript(url){    
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    if( url === scriptFilesConfig){  // append it only if the urls match.   
     document.head.appendChild(script); 
    }
}
```

Comment: sometimes what will happen is `document.head.appendChild(script);` will be executed but before it is finished, another link will be clicked -> the first link's variable will be deleted and finally when the script is ready to execute..there will be script error. What should happen is that request to load script should be cancelled when the second link is clicked.

Comment: Maybe use a combination of the answers provided so far. Please remember to up-vote useful and relevant answers as this will motivate others to answer as well if they see gratuity is shown this way.

Comment: @Mumzee once you execute `document.head.appendChild(script);` you can disable all the other links right?

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comments, try something like this:

```
function makeScript(url)
{
    script = document.createElement("script");

    script.onload = function()
    {
        if (!this.abort)
        {
            document.head.appendChild(script);
            return;
        }
    };

    script.src = url;

    return script;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var js1 = makeScript('path/to/file.js');

js.abort = true; // will not run
```

So basically, all you need to do is onclick -> run a function that triggers the JavaScript above accordingly; maybe make an object that holds the last script loading, and have the "onclick" assign makeScript return element to that object where it can be replaced, or deleted.

Comment: `script.onload` will not be executed. Script has to be loaded then only onload can be fired.